# How to configure jenkins to give password while executing shell script in remote server

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a shell script to do deployment on a remote server. But I didn't have full root privileges for that server and it asks password for every steps (4-5 times while executing the script).

Now, I want to run the shell script using Jenkins. How to configure jenkins to give the password while executing the shell script in remote server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrong way 'round.  Change the server to allow key access and give Jenkins the key.

Comment: @stark Sorry, I t is a legacy server and I don't think management will agree to this approach.

Comment: Which commands you are running as a part of that script? Are you using any `sudo` commands?

Comment: @NirajNandane Yes I'm using sudo commands in the script.

Comment: You can add below in /etc/sudoers file on server where you are running script.
USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Comment: Replace USER with the actual user name which is running the script.

Answer (score 0):

Add `myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` in `/etc/sudoers`.

Note: Replace `myuser` with your actual username.